# c# how change a variable from another class

Tags: c#, class

I have a variabele called 'language' in the main form of my windows form application.

In a sub-form I have a combo box with which I need to change the value of 'language' **without making a new instance of the main form**

```
namespace MMI_WFA
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        int language;
            ...
            ...
    }
}


namespace MMI_WFA
{
    public partial class MENU : Form
    {
    ...

        private void cbo_Language_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function_to_Change_language_in_mainForm();
        }
    }
}
```

So can I change a variable in the main form, with an event of an other form?

EDIT: I change this but window in `this.window`has red underlines.

```
public MENU(MainWindow window) // main constructor
        {
            this.window = window;
            InitializeComponent();
            cbo_SerialPort.Items.AddRange(ports);
            //cbo_SerialPort.SelectedIndex = 2;           

            cbo_Baudrate.Items.AddRange(baudrates);
            //cbo_Baudrate.SelectedIndex = 1;

            cbo_ParityBits.Items.AddRange(partitybits);
            //cbo_ParityBits.SelectedIndex = 0;

            hideExtraSettings();
            fillLanguageBox();
            indexComboboxes();
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at [ask] and especially [mcve]. You might get better answers to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your `Menu`-form doesn't have the instance of the main form(which you could pass in the constructor or as property) you could still get it with this `OpenForms.OfType<MainWindow>`-"trick":

```
var main = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainWindow>().First();
main.Language = 1;
```

You need to make it a public property:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    public int Language { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This does the trick, thank you alot. This is so useful. Pity C# has such complicated syntax to do such a simple thing

Comment: @bask185 That isn´t specific to C#, but to object orientation. This makes you having reference to what you want to change. In order to *change* an object you should *get* it before or at least have it sored somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference of your `MainWindow` to the other class in order to access its members. To achieve this create a constructor within your `MENU`-class that expects an instance of your `MainWindow`-class. Furthermore the member you want to change should be `public`, and preferably a property instead of a field:

```
namespace MMI_WFA
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        public int Language { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
    }

    public partial class MENU : Form
    {
        private readonly MainWindow window;

        public MENU(MainWindow window) { this.window = window; }

        private void cbo_Language_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.window.Language = //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile. I edited the OP with the new code.

Comment: Add a field on `MENU` to store the instance of MainWindow. `private readonly MainWindow window;`

Comment: @DanielMay Ooops, forgot that. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared very tiny example, how you can retrieve something from child form without passing Main form to child

Running main form

```
void Main()
{
    var main = new MainForm();
    main.ShowDialog();
}
```

Main form with 1 button only - to  ask child form for a number

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        var button = new Button();
        button.Click += button_pressed;
        button.Text = "Ask number";     
        this.Controls.Add(button);      
    }

    void button_pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var child = new SubForm();
        var result = child.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Entered number is {child.SelectedNumber}");
        }
    }
}
```

Child form will ask user to enter number. If user will enter number, then form will be closed with OK dialog result. Dialog result will help us to understand whether user selected something or just closed form.

```
class SubForm : Form
{
    public int SelectedNumber { get; set;}

    public SubForm()
    {
        var button = new Button();      
        var textBox = new TextBox();

        button.Click += (s, e) => {
            int i;
            if (int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out i))
            {
                this.SelectedNumber = i;
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("pls, enter number", "Warning",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }

        };  

        textBox.SetBounds(0, 0, 100, 20);
        button.SetBounds(100, 0, 30, 20);

        button.Text = "OK";     
        this.Controls.Add(textBox);
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }   
}
```